# Regular homotopy between closed curves

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I am stuck at an exercise regarding homotopies between closed curves. Specifically I want to find out whether there is a regular homotopy between the curves

$$
\beta: [0,2 \pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2, \ \beta(x):=(\cos(x),\sin(3x)) \\
\gamma: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2, \ \gamma(x):=(\cos(x),\sin(x)). 
$$

I tried to solve this by using the winding number. Here the tangent winding number of a closed curve is defined as $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \kappa ds=2 \pi n
$$

where $\kappa$ denotes the curvature of the curve. By the Whitney-Graustein theorem two closed curves are regularly homotopic if and only if they have the same winding number. The winding number of $\gamma$ is 1. Moreover we have

$$
\beta'(x)=(-\sin(x),3 \cos(3x))                                       \\
\beta''(x)=(-cos(x),-9 \sin(3x))                                      \\
|\beta'(x)|^2=\sin^2(x)+9 \cos^2(3x)                                  \\
\text{det}(\beta',\beta'')=9 \sin(x) \sin(3x)+3 \cos(x) \cos(3x)      \\
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \kappa ds
=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{\text{det}(\beta',\beta'')}{|\beta'(x)|^2} dx 
=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{9 \sin(x) \sin(3x)+3 \cos(x) \cos(3x) }{\sin^2(x)+9 \cos^2(3x)}.
$$

One can [numerically solve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%289%20%5Csin%28x%29%20%5Csin%283x%29%2B3%20%5Ccos%28x%29%20%5Ccos%283x%29%20%29%2F%28%5Csin%5E2%28x%29%2B9%20%5Ccos%5E2%283x%29%29%20from%200%20to%202*pi) the last integral and get $2 \pi \cdot 1$. This implies that the two curves have the same winding number and so the Whitney-Graustein theorem applies. But I am dissatisfied with this solution as it requires me to numerically compute an integral as there doesn't seem to be a analytical formula. So is there another way to argue that these curves are regularly homotopic?

Comment: Since $\pi_1 (\mathbb R^2)$ is trivial all curves are homotopic to a dot. Do you by chanch mean $\mathbb R^2 \backslash \{0\}$ ?

Comment: Also, it seems that you are using winding number formula for $\beta^\prime$ instead of $\beta$, for which I'd expect the number to be -1, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

There is a homotopy between the $\beta$ curve and the *clockwise* circle $\gamma$ where
$$
\beta(t) = (\cos t,3 \sin 3t)$$
$$ \gamma (t) = (\cos t, -\sin t)$$

This homotopy is defined as:
$$\Gamma (t, u) = (x(t,u), y(t,u))$$
$$= (1-u) \cos t + u\cos t,\;\;
3 (1-u) \sin 3t - u\sin t)$$
$$ = (\cos t, \;\;3\sin 3t - 3u\sin 3t - u \sin t)$$

We claim that $\forall t,u : \Gamma (t,u) \neq (0,0)$, i.e., the homotopy never goes through the origin and thus $\Gamma (t,u) \in \mathbb R^2 \backslash\{0\}$

Indeed, if $\Gamma (t_0,u_0) = (0,0)$ for some $t_0,u_0$ then $\cos t_0 = 0 \Rightarrow \sin t_0 = \pm 1 \wedge \sin
3t_0 = -\sin t_0$

But then, if we use $s_0 = \sin t_0$ we get:
$$y(t_0,u_0) = -3s_0 + 3us_0 - us_0
= s_0 (2u-3)$$
Since $0\leq u \leq 1$ we get $2u-3 \neq 0$ and thus $y(t_0,u_0) \neq 0$, q.e.d.